# Web middleware being applied to API routes in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have the following routes in place:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'api/v1', 'middleware' => 'api'], function() {
    Route::resource('authenticate', 'AuthenticateController', ['only' => ['index']]);
    Route::post('authenticate', 'AuthenticateController@authenticate');
    Route::resource('users', 'UserController');
});
```

The `UserController` has a test to ensure that when a user is submitted via `POST`, that it validates the input correctly. This should return a 422 when invalid, but it actually returns a 302. In Postman, it raises a CSRF token error, suggesting the `web` middleware group is being applied, which is not the behaviour I want.

How can I prevent this happening?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In `RouteServiceProvider.php` change

```
    $router->group([
        'namespace' => $this->namespace, 'middleware' => 'web',
    ], function ($router) {
        require app_path('Http/routes.php');
    });
```

to:

```
    $router->group([
        'namespace' => $this->namespace,
    ], function ($router) {
        require app_path('Http/routes.php');
    });
```

And then wrap your web routes with `Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'])` in `routes.php`. So api routes will be not affected by `web` middleware.

Comment: This was my exact issue. Thanks!

Comment: I was also not getting the $errors in the views and in route:list I was seeing web middleware as appearing twice. But, this was the solution to solve both.