# Display validation errors in Laravel 5.2 - $errors variable is empty

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am trying to display validation errors when going back to a View, in Laravel 5.2. The $errors variable is empty and in a similar question [Laravel 5.2 $errors not appearing in Blade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34438463/laravel-5-2-errors-not-appearing-in-blade) it has been proposed to:

(1) move the ShareErrorsFromSession middleware to the $middleware property

or

(2) wrap the relevant route with web middleware.

Of course, solution 1 (which works) is not applicable in my case because I have some API routes, as it is well stated in [Laravel 5.2 validation errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34420590/laravel-5-2-validation-errors).

To be more specific, I am using multiple authentication guard drivers and routes that use token authentication are stateless. So what us left is solution 2. It  should work, but it doesn't work (OR I am missing something). 
No matter if I place my routes (the ones in which I want to display validation errors) inside the group:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web','auth:web']], function () {        
    ...
}
```

or just inside:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function () {
    ...
}
```

the $errors variable seems empty. Dumping the variable gives:

```
object(Illuminate\Support\ViewErrorBag)#209 (1) {
  ["bags":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
}
```

The web group is typically defined in kernel.php as:

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,            
            \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
        ],

        'api' => [
            'throttle:60,1',
        ],
    ];
```

My controller looks like:

```
$form = Input::all();   
$rules = Config::get('validation.contact');            
$validation = Validator::make($form,$rules);

if ($validation->fails()){             
    return Redirect::back()->withErrors($validation);
} else {
    ...
}
```

Any ideas?

UPDATE (after answered):

You were right Alexander! I missed that recent change. But what about API routes that need not invoke these middlewares? Should we revert this change as described in [Web middleware being applied to API routes in Laravel 5.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36478187/web-middleware-being-applied-to-api-routes-in-laravel-5-2/36478268) ? If yes, then maybe it is better to strip middlewares from web group and put them in a new group (e.g myweb). This way we are not messing with the framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running **Laravel 5.2.27 and later**, you don't need to include "web" middleware in your routes. Because, starting from the mentioned version, it is already implicitly included by default. In fact, re-including that middleware can cause some odd issues. Source: [Validation error in Laravel - $errors array does not get populated after the validation failure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36503825/validation-error-in-laravel-errors-array-does-not-get-populated-after-the-val)